# Using watchdog python to watch for file, if it see's changes, execute another python script then wait again

Tags: python-3.x, python-watchdog

```
import sys
import time
import logging, os
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


class Watcher:

    DirectoryToWatch = 'C:\\Users\\dbeiler\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\New folder\\'

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()
    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DirectoryToWatch, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
            time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print ("Error")
            self.observer.join()

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'modified':
            # Take any action here when a file is first created.
            os.system('python writetodata.py')
            sys.exit
            time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Watcher()
    w.run()
```

The application works when i copy a file to the location, it will execute my script, however the script keeps cycling,  i would like it to stop and wait for another file once its already been written, not sure what im missing

I moved one of my directory folders, and now its writing to my output excel file twice, i assume its because 1.) its being opened, and 2.) its saving.

Comment: I need a loop of some sort

Comment: The observer already "loops". It is continually checking the specified directory for changes.

Comment: Yeah, im having the same issue as this guy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587415/python-watchdog-modified-and-created-duplicate-events

Answer (score 1):

how about looking for a specific object type only like xlsx'?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).